# adjusting time (h:i:s) and dividing time in an integer using PHP

Tags: php, time, divide

I have a total time output:

**Fig. A**

```
01:02:00
```

I want it to be displayed like this:

**Fig. B**

```
00:01:02
```

I want the hour and minute on the **Fig. A**, should move on the minute and seconds on the **Fig. B**

I also want to divide the **Fig. B** to an integer and get the quotient.

**Fig. C**

```
$b = 00:01:02;
$quotient = $b / $integer;

echo $quotient;
```

ex:

```
00:01:00 / 4 = 00:00:15
```

Comment: what quotient value u are expecting after dividing with integer ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty i updated my example. please check it again. thanks.

Comment: No directly its not possible u can get the hour value say 1 and then 1*60/4 = 15 then display that in a desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Datetime::createFromFormat](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) for the first part.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', '01:02:00');

echo $date->format("s:H:i");
```